# Comparing the performance of a digital communication sim against a reference

Tags: digital-communications, noise, gaussian, snr, fsk

I have a complex baseband simulation of binary FSK modulation and demodulation. The modulated signal $s[k]$ is computed as

$$
s[k] = e^{-j2\pi f_ik/f_s} , i \in [0,1]
$$

where the sampling rate is $f_s = 1$ MSPS, the two frequency shifts are $f_0 = 35 kHz$ and $f_1 = 90kHz$. Each FSK symbol has $N$ samples per symbol, and let's say $N=1000$, therefore the symbol (bit rate also in this case) is $R_b = (1e6)/(1000) = 1000$ bits per second. To be clear, that means to send a "0" then $s$ would look like the following:
$$
s[k] = e^{-j2\pi (35e3)k/(1e6)}, k \in [0,1000)
$$

I add complex gaussian noise white noise to form the received signal:

$$
y[k] = s[k] + w[k]
$$

where $w[k]$ is drawn from a zero mean complex normal distribution $\mathcal{CN}(0, \sigma^2) $. The noisy signal $y[k]$ is then fed to a demodulation chain to extract the estimates of the transmitted bits and a BER is computed.

I would like to compare the performance of my system with the optimal coherent and non-coherent binary FSK BER curves - however to do so I need to understand how to compute and adjust the $E_b/N_0$ of my system. This is where I get lost a bit, I thought the following equation relating carrier to noise ratio would help here:

$$
CNR_{db} = \frac{E_b}{{N_{0}}_{db}} + 10\log_{10}(\frac{R_b}{B})
$$

Plugging in $R_b = 1000$ bps and $B=1e6$ (complex bandwidth) indicates that the second term is -30 dB. Using this equation along with the fact that my signal power is 1 (due to the magnitude of the complex exponential), I computed a variance to generate the AWGN samples at a Eb/N0 of 13 dB but the noise level is *much* higher than I'd expect.

Pretty sure I'm missing something major here and it'd be great if someone could lay out how this should actually work.

Comment: With 13dB Eb/N0, and -30dB bandwidth ratiom you would get only -17dB CNR. Yes this is too much noise (nearly 50x power compared to signal).

Comment: I am really not familiar with simulation by varying Eb/N0. Have you tried directly varying noise variance without Rb/B ratio? That is just SNR and ignoring the -30dB term.